# Thymeleaf, get first element list of an object that is already iterating

Tags: html, thymeleaf

```
<tr th:each="current : ${object.list}"  >
    <td th:text="${current.currentList...???}"></td>
...
```

I have an object that has a list.

"current" has also a list inside it called currentList.

currentList has only one element called objectTwo. I want to access to the attributes of objectTwo.

It's possible?

Comment: You can access the first element of the list the same way as in a java code. For example: current.currentList.get(0)

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will work for you.

```
<tr th:each="current : ${object.list}"  >
    <td th:text="${current.currentList[0].objectTwo...}"></td>
...
```